# How to use loop in lambda functions in JAVA?

Tags: java, lambda, filter, java-stream

I want to create a FileNameFilter using a lambda function.

My main problem is that I want to introduce a loop inside the function.
I tried using filters but I am unable to create filters based on external list.

Following is my code:

```
    File targetDir = new File(path);
    FilenameFilter deleteFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            for(String tag: pageTagsList){
                if(name.equals(tag))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
    File[] foundFiles = targetDir.listFiles(deleteFilter);
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
File[] foundFiles = targetDir.listFiles(
            (dir,name)->pageTagsList.stream()
            .filter(//code to filter here)
            .orElse(false)
            );
```

Is there a correct way to do this?

Comment: Maybe this is a contrived example and the point is to know how to iterate within a lambda body in general, but if not, the best solution would be to use a `pageTagsSet` of type `Set<String>`. Looking up in a `HashSet` is way faster than iterating over a list.  So `(dir,name)->pageTagsList.contains(name)` would do it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have a lambda be any code block (though any variables referenced from inside of it must be final). For your desired outcome you can do something like the following:

```
File[] foundFiles = targetDir.listFiles((dir, name) -> pageTagsList.stream().anyMatch(name::equals));
```

Answer (score 2):

A lambda can contain a block of code. The syntax is like this:

```
(params) -> {
    // Some code.

    for (Element elem : elements) {
        // Some code using elem.
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> tags = pageTagList
                   .stream()
                   .filter(t -> t.equals(name)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you need explanation of anything above, just ask in comment. I find this code self explaining.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {    
    return pageTagsList.stream()
        .filter(name::equals)
        .findAny()
        .isPresent()
}
```

- This is just showcase of returning true/false, answer from Aaron Davis is most elegant

Comment: Actually, the most elegant solution is `pageTagsList.contains(name)`. Since Java 2…